# Central limit theorem on small scales

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence, probability-limit-theorems, central-limit-theorem

Say $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are iid, bounded,  symmetric random variables with  mean $0$, variance 1 and a smooth density. At what scale does $\frac{X_1+\cdots+X_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ "look like" the normal distribution?

If the $X_i$ are uniform random variables on $[-1,1]$ then it seems that a modification of the characteristic function proof of Berry-Esseen gives that $$\mathbb{E}f\left(\frac{X_1+\cdots+X_n}{\sqrt{n/3}}\right) = \mathbb{E}f(G)+ O(n^{-1} \||f\||_1) + O(e^{-cn} \||D^2f\||_2)\,,$$ where $G$ is the standard unit Gaussian on $\mathbb{R}$. This suggest that $\frac{X_1+\cdots+X_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ "looks" gaussian down to exponential scales, however I am unable to find a reference addressing this situation. The standard examples showing sharpness of Berry-Esseen usually involve discrete random variables. But this calculation suggests that an improved Berry-Esseen holds on much smaller scales when the distribution of $X_i$ is smooth.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By any chance, does https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality suffice for your purposes? (It shows concentration bounds, which is a much weaker compared to what you ask in the question. But often this is what you actually need)

Comment: That does not suffice, unfortunately. I don't think Hoeffding gives a fine description of the distribution's behaviour within a standard deviation of the mean, which is really what I am looking for.